# I need to write on new form the column names of a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to get the column names and save it on other form as Labels and get a new textbox for each label. So I'm trying this code and that is the answer. I debugged it, everything works fine. Any suggestions where the problem can be?
I only get the first column name.
[image]

```
        int location = 10;
        int locationHeight = 10;
        int locationHeightlbl = 10;

        TextBox[] txtBox = new TextBox[DM.dataGridView1.Columns.Count];
        Label[] labels = new Label[DM.dataGridView1.Columns.Count];

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in DM.dataGridView1.Columns)
        {


            labels[column.Index] = new Label();
            labels[column.Index].Text = column.HeaderText;
            labels[column.Index].Location = new Point(location, locationHeightlbl);

            txtBox[column.Index] = new TextBox();
            txtBox[column.Index].Location = new Point(location, locationHeight + 25);
            this.Controls.Add(labels[column.Index]);
            this.Controls.Add(txtBox[column.Index]);

            locationHeight += 25;
            locationHeightlbl += 25;


        }
```

Comment: the rest of the labels is hidden behind the textboxes. How did you intend the layout to be? Have you tried to increase `locationHeight` by 50 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is using `TableLayoutPanel` ok in your application? I recommend using it. Take a look at the code:

```
        TextBox[] txtBox = new TextBox[DM.dataGridView1.Columns.Count];
        Label[] labels = new Label[DM.dataGridView1.Columns.Count];

        TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel = new TableLayoutPanel() { AutoSize = true };
        tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        int n = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in DM.dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            labels[column.Index] = new Label();
            labels[column.Index].Text = column.HeaderText;
            tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
            tableLayoutPanel.SetCellPosition(labels[column.Index], new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(0, n++));
            tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(labels[column.Index]);

            txtBox[column.Index] = new TextBox();
            tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
            tableLayoutPanel.SetCellPosition(txtBox[column.Index], new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(0, n++));
            tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(txtBox[column.Index]);
        }

        Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel);
```

In addition consider using `FlowLayoutPanel` as well.

Answer (score 0):

as already mentioned in the comment. Your labels are well hidden behind the textboxes. 
To solve this, just make the increment larger:

```
locationHeight += 50;
locationHeightlbl += 50;
```

But I would suggest in such a scenario to use a [FlowLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel?view=netframework-4.8). It will order the elements on its own. You only need to specify the `FlowDirection`. (and it is way less code:)

```
FlowLayoutPanel panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
panel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;

foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    panel.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = column.HeaderText });
    panel.Controls.Add(new TextBox());                
}
this.Controls.Add(panel);
```